# What Algorithm to Use for a List Swap with No Duplication

Tags: sql, node.js, algorithm, grouping

I have a scenario where a number of organizations have joined together to swap names to increase the size of their respective mailing lists. I have a pool of names, each tagged to their source organization. Each org has provided a subset of their full list, and is entitled to an output of up to the number of names they put into the pool, but with these restrictions:

- an org should not receive a name already on their full list
- each name should only be swapped once (should be allocated to only a single output grouping)

Separate from this pool I have the full lists of each organization (hashed to obfuscate the details, but not particularly relevant to the question), so I have the data necessary to determine which records are available to swap to each list.

My question: is there a grouping/clustering algorithm that would apply in this case, where we want to cluster based the organization(s) that are entitled to them, with the aforementioned requirement of each record being distributed to a single group and each group's size not exceeding the number of records originally sourced to that organization.

The data is currently in MySQL tables and I will likely use Node/JS for implementation, but I'm mainly seeking general advice on the algorithm.

Thanks in advance for any advice you might have!

Comment: You need to define this a bit more specifically, for instance, what happens when the conditions can't be satisfied i.e. one organization can provide more names than it can possibly receive, etc.

Comment: We'd want to maximize the amount they get back, but if the names provided by other orgs are all already on a given org's list, there's not much that can be done and they would end up receiving fewer than they provided.